# Is it possible to disable flycheckspell for specific file names in text-mode?

Tags: flyspell

I am actively using `flyspell` on all text files under `text-mode`.

For example: Under `requirements.txt` text file I am keeping my python packages where I do not need to enable `flyspell`. But since it is a text file flyspell keep does its checks. So I want to disable flyspell for specific file names like: `requirements.txt` and so on. It also enable in `yaml-mode` even I did not enable it.

My setup:

```
(flyspell-mode 1)
(setq flyspell-issue-message-flag nil
      ispell-local-dictionary "en_US"
      ispell-program-name "aspell"
      ispell-extra-args '("--sug-mode=ultra"))

(dolist (hook '(text-mode-hook))
     (add-hook hook (lambda () (flyspell-mode 1))))
    (dolist (hook '(change-log-mode-hook log-edit-mode-hook))
      (add-hook hook (lambda () (flyspell-mode -1))))
```

Comment: `yaml-mode` is derived from `text-mode`, so it runs the `text-mode-hook`.

Comment: Do you really want that first line in the code?

Comment: Actually I don't. I took first line from a documentation and it remain as it is. Should I delete it?

Comment: I think so: you don't want to turn it on globally; that's why you turn it on (and off) in all the hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function that turns off the mode if the filename matches a list and add the function to the `find-file-hook`. Something like this:

```el
(defvar no-flyspell-list '("requirements.txt"))

(defun turn-off-flyspell-if-match ()
  (if (member (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)) no-flyspell-list)
      (flyspell-mode -1)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'turn-off-flyspell-if-match)
```

As I mentioned in a comment, `yaml-mode` is derived from `text-mode` so the `text-mode-hook` is run and it turns on `flyspell-mode`. But the derived mode hook, `yaml-mode-hook` is run *after* the parent mode hook, so you can add a turn-off function to it:

```
(add-hook `yaml-mode-hook (lambda () (flyspell-mode -1)))
```

Or add it to your list of other modes (`change-log-mode-hook`, `log-edit-mode-hook`) where you turn off `flyspell-mode`.

Comment: Is order of calling the `add-hook` important? To be safe I put end of the file.

Comment: No, the only constraint is that the hook variable is defined, so the package where it is defined must be loaded already. That is not a problem for `find-file-hook`: that is done before your init file is loaded.